# selecting and deleting a row

Tags: jquery

For adding rows i wrote the code like this

```
$('#tab1 tbody ').append('<tr id='+i+'><td>'+k+'</td><td>'+l+'</td><td>'+m+'</td></tr>');
```

in the previous snippet `i` is global value..

Now if i am trying to select newly added row it is not recognizing.. for selecting i wrote like this

```
$('#tab1 td').click(function(){
 alert(i);
 $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Do you see any mistakes?

Comment: @ never use numbers for ids and classes , you cannot see the error directly but it can give weird results while manimulate dom using jquery or javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your td elements are having invalid id's. ***ID should not start with numbers***. Try appending some static text before `i`.

Also you have to use [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event to get the elements that are generated in js

```
$('#tab1 td').live("click", function(){
   alert(i);
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: now i wrote like this $('#tab1 tr').click(function(){
 //alert(this.id);
 $(this).remove();
});

Comment: all rows are going to remove  what to do

Comment: You have to use like `$('#tab1 tr').live("click", function(){`, since the `<tr>` elements are also generated at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

You're only adding the `click` handler to the `<td>` elements that exist when the `.click()` line executes.

You need to call the `.live()` function, which will add your handler to all elements that match the selector, no matter when they were created.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
$('#tab1 td').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('#tab1 td').live('click', function(){
```

Answer (score 4):

That is added at runtime , so you should use live instead of click

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('#tab1 td').live('click', function() {
  alert(i);
 $(this).parent().remove();
});
```